# How to get the file path using key from webconfig file

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, wcf, c#-4.0

I have JSON file stored in my D drive. I have mentioned the same in web config file. Please refer the below code

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="inputFilePath" value="D:\products.json"/>
    </appSettings>
```

When I try to get the file path using the below code, I am getting null value.

```
    string filepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inputFilePath"];
```

Please can any one help me on this

Answer (score 0):

you need to call like this

```
string filepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inputFilePath"].ToString();
```

Comment: I have tried using the above code but I am getting An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'.

Comment: @anithalm are you able to get the stringpath or is it null value?

Comment: @anithalm Your implementation of it must be incorrect. This definitely works for retrieving key values from a config file.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this - [How to: Read Application Settings from the Web.config File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx)

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig1 =
                System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
            if (rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement customSetting = 
                    rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings["customsetting1"];
                if (customSetting != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("customsetting1 application string = \"{0}\"", 
                        customSetting.Value);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("No customsetting1 application string");
            }
```

//Config file

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="customsetting1" value="Some text here"/>
</appSettings>
```

You'll need to add a reference to System.Configuration in your project's references folder.

Add namespace

```
using System.Configuration;
```

then get file path

```
String path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inputFilePath"];
```

More References:
[AppSettings](http://www.dotnetperls.com/appsettings)
[How to read appSettings section in the web.config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147220/how-to-read-appsettings-section-in-the-web-config-file)
[Getting configuration settings from web.config/app.config using class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685259/getting-configuration-settings-from-web-config-app-config-using-class-library)
[Reading settings from app.config or web.config in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. This suggests that the `<appSettings>` isn't in the executing project. For example, if you have a web project and some other class library and the class library refers to `<appSettings>`, that setting needs to be in the website's web.config. If your class library has its own app.config it's not going to be read. 
Whatever is executing - website, web forms, console app, etc, - that's where the `<appSettings>` needs to be, regardless of what is trying to read it.